# URL_REWRITE passing parameters with "?"

Tags: php, url-rewriting, parameter-passing

I'm doing a job for a person who has a website that use the URL rewrite mod, and the parameters are passed like this:
www.site.com/val1/val2/val3 and i get them with a getPararm(n) function.

I had to implement a credit card payment system, and this service, once the payment is done,
Send me back the answer to a page that I choose, in this way:
www.yourSite.com?a=val1&b=val2

Ofc I choosed a page of that website, so i get an answer like this:
www.site.com/confirmed/?a=val1&b=val2

With some string manipulation i would be able to get all the string after the final "/", and separate them in 2 separate string $a=val and $b=val2, but because of the "?" it doesnt read anything after it.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's impossible to say what exactly the problem is here. Any sensible mod_rewrite setup would use `[QSA]`, so the URL `/foo?bar=baz` is rewritten to something like `my.php?url=foo&bar=baz`. Then in PHP you just use `$_GET['bar']`.

Comment: What does the rewrite do? If it isn't stripping the query string, you should be able to get the variables as normal.

Comment: just remove ? from your string and use your string manipulation to get your params: you can remove it using str_replace like this str_replace('?', '', 'www.site.com/confirmed/?a=val1&b=val2')

Answer (score 0):

@deceze thnk i didn't know that if i would use $_GET['a'] for example it was going to read the part after, thnk you!
I was using  $_GET['a'] withouth the "?" so it wasnt going to see it, or getParam(0) with the "?" so i couldnt get anything. I didn't try this way